# How do I add a row to a dataset in ADF dataflows

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

New to ADF and could use some help, I have a 2 column data set I would like to add an additional row to the data set. I have Columns : "CHANNEL" and "CHANNEL_ID" with values as following [Source Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13K47.png) and would like to add fields: '0' and 'blank' to those columns to produce the result below[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP5WZ.png). Is this kind of transformation possible within my dataflow?

I've tried to pivot the columns and add a derived column for the '0' field and then pivot those columns again, but I was not certain that what I did was right and I believe there has to be a simpler way than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a new row `channel_id=0 and channel='blank'`, I followed below approach.

- Two source transformations are taken with the same datasets as in below image.

[image]

- Then filter transformation is added to one of the source transformations and filter is given to select one of the rows from the dataset.
  filter condition:`channel_id='52'`

[image]

- derived column transformation is added and settings are give as,

```
Column: Expression
channel='Blank'
channel_id='0'
```

[image]

- Then Union transformation is added and derived column output and source1 output are given as input to the union transfromation.

[image]

*Result of Union transformation:*
[image]

**Dataflow script**

```scala
source(output(
channel as string,
channel_id as string
),
allowSchemaDrift: true,
validateSchema: false,
ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1
source(output(
channel as string,
channel_id as string
),
allowSchemaDrift: true,
validateSchema: false,
ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source2
filter1 derive(channel =  'blank',
channel_id =  '0') ~> derivedColumn1
source1, derivedColumn1 union(byName: true)~> union1
source2 filter(channel_id=='52') ~> filter1
union1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,
validateSchema: false,
skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> sink1
```

By this way, you can add a row in dataflow.

Comment: This helped greatly, managed to replicate without needing to create an additional source. Achieved the same result by creating an additional branch from the same source.